# OK Gimap ready for requests from *USER BAD Unknown command*

Tags: php, gmail, imap

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$uname = "*****@gmail.com";
$pass = "*****";
$data[1] = "";
$k=0;
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://imap.gmail.com', '993', $errno, $errstr);
if(!$fp){
    echo "WRONG!";
    exit;
}else{
    echo "OK!<br />";
    fputs($fp, "USER $uname\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "PASS $pass\r\n");
    $message = fputs($fp, "STAT\r\n");
    echo $message . "<br />";
    $row = fputs($fp, "RETR 1\r\n");
    while($k != 5){
        $row = fgets($fp, 512);
        $data[1] .= $row;
        $k++;
    }
    echo $data[1];
    //list($header, $body, ) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data[1]);
    //echo $body;
    fputs($fp, "QUIT\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

What is this?

```
OK Gimap ready for requests from 83.66.211.216 io5mb34879192bkb
USER BAD Unknown command io5mb34879192bkb
PASS BAD Unknown command io5mb34879192bkb
BAD invalid tag io5mb34879192bkb
RETR BAD Unknown command io5mb34879192bkb
```

How can i read my mails on imap without `imap_open()` functions

Comment: Use IMAP commands, not POP3 commands. IMAP is a much more complicated protocol, detailed in RFC 3501. For example, you log in with a LOGIN command.